# Is it possible to block a site-level owner from a library?

Tags: permissions

Due to business reasons, there are multiple site owners for a SharePoint site for which I'm the primary administrator. I have a need to store a file on the SharePoint site to take advantage of version controls, but the file contains confidential information to which only some of the administrators (and two individuals outside the admin group) should have access.

However, after testing the permission structure that we need to implement, we found that even after breaking permissions inheritence and removing all users except those that should have access, people in the owners usergroup for the main site still had access to the heavily-restricted document library.

It is not feasible for us to change the owners usergroup, and setting up a separate SharePoint site strictly for this one file is not an option. Is there a way in SharePoint 2010 to configure the document library so as to exclude site-level admins who should not have access to it?

Answer (score 1):

you can't modify  / restrict the site collection administrator permissions. You have no other choice then either create another site collection or enabling the auditing.

What i am thinking, you can create the another site collections & set permission over there then put the link on your main site. so when somebody click on it, only the person having access will get it.

Other option is enable the auditing on that list/library and also remove the link from quick launch and top navigation bar.

Comment: Also including a password on the file is an option, if its an Office document.

Comment: I'd like to avoid password protecting the file itself as while it contains sensitive financial information the file still needs to be accessed conveniently by several individuals who have no reasonable expectation of being able to remember the password without recording it somewhere and creating a security risk. As for the site collection notion, it's not exactly feasible to the best of my knowledge, but looks like I'm going to have to present it as the only real option to my boss. Better than nothing, I suppose...